# how to have fix height when you hover over link

Tags: html, css

This is not my actual code. I am creating drop down menu, but I had one problem so I deleted all the code, so I can have minimal code for my question.

My problem is when I hover over my link, I am increasing the font size for anchor tag which is fine, but it also increasing the height for `li` element, which understandable. In short I know why it is happening, 
I just want the solution. When I hover over my element I want to increase the font size, but not the size of `li` element, which is parent element. If you don't understand the problem just read the comment in CSS code.

> I only want to use css for the solution

```css
/*basic style no need to pay attention*/

* {
  font-family: helvetica;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu li {
  flex: 1;
}

ul ul li {
  display: flex;
}

.menu>li a {
  background: black;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}


/*
    ####
    increase the font size, but not the size for li
    ####*/

a:hover {
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Plumbing</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Heating</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu sub-menu2">
          <li><a href="#">Residential</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Industrial</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Electrical</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could probably try just setting the `line-height` to the `px` value of the initial font-size (i.e. `a { line-height: 14px; }`), or you could use maybe a `transform:scale(1.1);` on hover instead of a `font-size` increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `li` height is changing because your default `line-height` changes with the size of your text. Try defining `line-height` for your `li` elements so that they stay the same height.

Answer (score 1):

```css
/*basic style no need to pay attention*/

* {
  font-family: helvetica;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu li {
  flex: 1;
}

ul ul li {
  display: flex;
}

.menu>li a {
  background: black;
  min-height: 36px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}


/*
    ####
    increase the font size, but not the size for li
    ####*/

a:hover {
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Plumbing</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">Heating</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu sub-menu2">
          <li><a href="#">Residential</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Commercial</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Industrial</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Electrical</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Add min-height to "a" tag

.menu > li a { background: black none repeat scroll 0 0; min-height: 36px; }